# Percentage of people who have good credit ratings given that their ratings will improve

Tags: conditional-probability

> Suppose that **75%** of all people with credit records improve their credit ratings within three years. Suppose that **18%** of the population at large have poor credit records, and of those only **30%** will improve their credit ratings within three years.
>
> What percentage of the people who will improve their credit records within the next three years are the ones who currently have good credit ratings?

I defined $A$ as the event that a randomly selected person has a poor rating and $B$ as the event that a randomly selected person will improve their rating within three years.
$$P(A) = \frac{18}{100}, P(B) = \frac{75}{100}$$
$$P(A^cB)=P(B)-P(A)=\frac{57}{100}$$
$$P(A^c|B)=\frac{P(A^cB)}{P(B)}=\frac{19}{25}$$
However, this answer is wrong. I'm not sure where the *30%* statistic comes in. What am I doing wrong and what approach should I take instead?

**EDIT:** I was able to solve the problem with your help. Thank you! I think my reasoning for this new solution should be sound.
$$P(A) = \frac{18}{100}, P(B) = \frac{75}{100}, P(B|A)=\frac{30}{100}$$
$$P(A^c|B)=1-P(A|B)=1-\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}=1-\frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}=\frac{116}{125}$$

Comment: +1 because you show your own effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try visualizing the situation for 1.000 people.

750 people will improve their ratings.

180 people have poor ratings - meaning the remaining 820 have good ratings.

30% of the 180 people will improve - that is 54 people.

Since a total of 750 people improved that means that from the 
820 people with good ratings we need 750-54=696 people to improve.

So we have 696 out of 820 people.

Try "translating" this specific (n=1000) example to probabilities.

Comment: +1 but you mean $696$, not $694$.